# Embed and word Count not working for wp_editor instance

Tags: wp-editor

When using the wp_editor() function to have an editor, I do not see the standard word count and am unable to embed files.

In the default post editor, word count is shown, and youtube urls are automatically converted into embeds.

What am I missing here?

Added the wp_editor with this code:`wp_editor( $data, 'welcome_text', array( 'wpautop' => false, 'textarea_name' => 'welcome_text' ) );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after discussing this in the #core channel on Slack, got notified the embed and wordcount only work for posts (and CPTs).